# Are there any limits on MYSQL DB & Table Sizes

Tags: mysql, database

I have that a mysql table with 2M+ rows, and overall database size is 2.3GB. PHPmyadmin runs out of memory retrieving the table, however i will never be pulling 2M rows.
Are there any limitations i should concern myself with?

My machine:
4 GB RAM,
1x i3 540 3.06GHz
120GB SSD HD

I use NodeJS to query the database, I only use myPHPadmin to manage it

Comment: Please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-size-limit.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/database-count-limit.html

Comment: It depends on the filesystem most of the time and in the system memory (RAM) your machine has. If you'll have a lot of data in a, let's say, 1GB machine, it will run out of memory quickly, especially in multi-user environments. Considering that, you'll have to work your queries a little to make them do "smart" selects (i.e. do not select all rows and then filter, query in a way that MySQL will filter automatically).

Comment: @AlejandroIván See edit for specs. I query only whats needed `'SELECT row1,row2 FROM table WHERE id = id'`

Comment: Weird. Are you using indexes?

Comment: @AlejandroIván No I'm not saying it's degrading, only if i should be worried as the database is growing. But no indexes, only primary key (id)

Comment: @GameDevGuru neither did I. I was thinking that maybe, if you use indexes, then the table won't be entirely read, so it could avoid memory issues, but I can't tell for sure. Maybe you should try it. Good luck with your problem!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is terrible for pulling many rows of data. It just doesn't scale well with large memory usage or large arrays. If you really want PHP MyAdmin to output your table you will need to up the PHP memory limit.

Your DB itself should be fine. I think any MySQL limits would be on the operating system itself. However, table performance does degrade as tables increase in size. The point where degradation of performance happens is entirely dependent on the table structure and its use and the system it is running on.

Comment: See edit for specs. I only use PHP with PHPmyadmin to manage the database. I pull data with NodeJS using "smart" selects.

Comment: As long as you aren't selecting large portions of your table you should be fine. I believe NodeJS does have some memory issues with large datasets still (it has been a while since I read up on it). As for the actual database's performance it is very dependent on the datatypes of the columns, the indexes, how it is used.

Comment: The table consists of 8 columns, (2 int, 2 tinyint, 3 longtext, 1 text). Most of the time i query only for 1 row by the id (int).

Comment: As long a the id is the primary key or indexed you should be fine. However, longtext and text do have some performance implications since they are not stored in the row itself. Also be very careful with longtext and text. longtext can go up to 4gb of text data which if you actually try to load/transmit through NodeJS would shutdown your server. Again it's been a while since I looked at it but NodeJS was vulnerable to large transfers locking it up.

Comment: The text data should never get that large, at the moment the largest longtext is < 1MB